# How do I get images to upload to the server with TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, tinymce

I am trying to store images added via the TinyMCE editor to the server. It appears as if the file that handles image uploads is never reached. I might be blind, but it seems as though I followed their documentation, so nothing is wrong.

Here's the TinyMCE initialization:

```
//Initialize the TinyMCE text editor
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#tinymce-selector',
        menubar: 'edit format view insert',
        removed_menuitems: 'backcolor lineheight fontfamily fontsize',
        plugins: 'lists advlist accordion anchor charmap emoticons image link media quickbars searchreplace code table',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | bold italic underline forecolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | insert | emoticons charmap',
        toolbar_groups: {
            insert: {
                icon: 'browse',
                tooltip: 'Insert',
                items: 'link | image media | table | bullist numlist'
            }
        },
        image_upload_url: 'assets/functions/news-manager/image-uploader.php',
        block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Header 1=h1; Sub Header 1=h2; Sub Header 2=h3', //Sets the content blocks for the editor
        quickbars_insert_toolbar: false, //Disables quick image and quick table toolbar
        link_default_target: '_blank', //Sets target of links to _blank by default
        media_dimensions: false, //Disables dimensions on media input (set automatically)
        relative_urls: false, //Disables relative URL functionality - links will be outputted as they are inputted
        mobile: { //Enables the menubar on mobile phones
            menubar: true
        },
        content_style: `
                        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
                        body {
                            font-family: 'Open Sans'
                        }`, //Defines the font for the text editor
        encoding: 'xml', //Encodes quotes and other special characters
        min_height: 750, //Defines the minimum height of the editor
        style_formats: [ //Defines options show under Format -> Formats
            { title: 'Headings', items: [
                { title: 'Header 1', format: 'h1' },
                { title: 'Sub Header 1', format: 'h2' },
                { title: 'Sub Header 2', format: 'h3' }
            ]},
            { title: 'Inline', items: [
                { title: 'Bold', format: 'bold' },
                { title: 'Italic', format: 'italic' },
                { title: 'Underline', format: 'underline' },
                { title: 'Strikethrough', format: 'strikethrough' },
                { title: 'Superscript', format: 'superscript' },
                { title: 'Subscript', format: 'subscript' },
                { title: 'Code', format: 'code' }
            ]},
            { title: 'Align', items: [
                { title: 'Left', format: 'alignleft' },
                { title: 'Center', format: 'aligncenter' },
                { title: 'Right', format: 'alignright' },
                { title: 'Justify', format: 'alignjustify' }
            ]}
        ]
    });
```

For image upload URL, I also tried a full address https://example.com/...... which didn't work either.

This is the AJAX where the form is submitted and the images are to be uploaded.

```
//Submission handler for the form
    var submission_flag = 0;
    $('#new-post-form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        if (submission_flag === 0) {

            submission_flag = 1;

            //Upload tinyMCE images to the server
            tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) { 
                
                console.log('images uploaded');

            });

            const form = $(this),
                url = form.attr('action');
            
            tinyMCE.triggerSave(); //Save TinyMCE Data

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                global: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    response = JSON.parse(data);

                    if (response.flag == 0) {
                    
                        //Send the user to the new post (if live) OR back to the manager (if draft)
                        // window.location.replace(response.url);
                        console.log('post upload complete!');

                    } else {
                    
                        //Report errors to the client
                        openStateNotification('error', response.errors);

                        //Remove hidden 'is-draft' flag element
                        $("#js-is-draft").remove();

                        //Reset flags
                        draft_flag = 0;
                        submission_flag = 0;

                    }
                    
                },
.....
```

I obviously don't understand something, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.